# How to solve following Relational Algebra query

Tags: relational-algebra

On the relational algebra exam I had yesterday there was a question I couldn't answer and want to know how it would be solved. The constraint on the question was I wasn't allowed to use aggregate functions which I found difficult. The schema is as follows.

```
EMPLOYEE = {id, name, phone} with id PK
COURSE = {course_no, title, subject} with course_no PK
COMPLETED = {course_no, student_id, grade, semester} with {course_no,id,semester} PK
```

The question went: List the pairs of employees who have completed the same courses and have always completed these same courses in the same years and have never received grade 'D' in any of these courses. List each pair?

If any could shed some light that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you first build a query that joins the tables together to form the desired list of properties per employee.

Then you copy those two queries and join the results on course_no and - I guess - semester (and remember to exclude the rows where the same employee id appears on both sides).

Finally you filter this result by grade.

There are other variations possible, but this is the general idea.